# Troubles importing manim

Tags: python, ffmpeg, manim

```
import manim

class Vectors(VectorScene):

    def construct(self):
        self.add_axes()
        self.add_plane()
        self.add(self.get_basis_vectors())
        self.wait()
```

thats the code i am using, i just install manim (choco install manimce) 0.17.3 and ffmpeg 6.0 using choco. python version 3.11.3. i run it opening the cmd on the directory of the file an tiping:

```
python -m manim startingmanim.py
```

but get the following error/output:

```
Manim Community v0.17.3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\tools\Manim\Lib\site-packages\manim\__main__.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\tools\Manim\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\tools\Manim\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\tools\Manim\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\tools\Manim\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\tools\Manim\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\tools\Manim\Lib\site-packages\manim\cli\render\commands.py", line 111, in render
    for SceneClass in scene_classes_from_file(file):
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\tools\Manim\Lib\site-packages\manim\utils\module_ops.py", line 129, in scene_classes_from_file
    module = get_module(file_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\tools\Manim\Lib\site-packages\manim\utils\module_ops.py", line 52, in get_module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Pablo\Downloads\startingmanim.py", line 1, in <module>
    from manimlib import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manimlib'
```

note that on my code the following sentence `from manimlib import *` doesnt even exists.
I dont know what to do. thanks in advace

Comment: It seems you are trying to use manimGL code in manimCE...

Comment: which code should i use? is there any difference? @JasonGrace

Comment: Try something simple, like from the quickstart in the manim documentation [here](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/tutorials/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are good. But when you want to use specific resources you would use the dot notation

```py
import manim

class Vectors(manim.VectorScene):

    def construct(self):
        self.add_axes()
        self.add_plane()
        self.add(self.get_basis_vectors())
        self.wait()
```

or you can import everything in manim if you don't want to write `manim.<assetName>` everytime.

```py
from manim import *

class Vectors(VectorScene):

    def construct(self):
        self.add_axes()
        self.add_plane()
        self.add(self.get_basis_vectors())
        self.wait()
```